# Match two nodes in cypher and and a relation between them

Tags: neo4j, cypher

An entry level question. I am trying out Desktop Neo4j v4.3.1. So far I have created to nodes with

`CREATE (n:CST {cst_id:'CST_ID_1'}) RETURN n`

`CREATE (n:CST {csT_id:'CST_ID_2'}) RETURN n`

`CREATE (n:CST {csT_id:'CST_ID_3'}) RETURN n`

Supposedly representing two customers. . What I would like to do is to

1. Match and return the two first nodes
2. Add an edge between the two first nodes

So far, I have tried

```
MATCH (c:CST),(d:CST)
WHERE c.cst_id='CST_ID_1' AND d.cst_id='CST_ID_2'
RETURN c,d
```

which returns nothing. Changing the AND to OR results in returning all three nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would like to point out that your `cst_id` is different. The first node has `cst_id` and the second and third have `csT_id` (notice the capital `T`). I'm unsure if that's intentional however, I will be constant in my example:

```
MATCH (a:CST {cst_id: "CST_ID_1"})
MATCH (b:CST {cst_id: "CST_ID_2"})
CREATE (a)-[:MY_EDGE_NAME]->(b)
```

Above I perform two matches and then create an edge between the two matched nodes called `MY_EDGE_NAME`. If `CST_ID_1` or `CST_ID_2` don't match the relationship will not be created.

Comment: Nice noticing the typo. The strange thing is that this was the cause of the problem. Thank you.